# Cannot install libhdf5-dev (or any hdf5 dependency) on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (arm64 -aarch64)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, sudo, libraries

I am trying to install hdf5 on Ubuntu 18.04 on Nvidia's Jetson Nano device (arm64 structure). Have attempted to do the basic recommended installation: `'sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev`

I have also tried '`sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev`', '`sudo apt install libhdf5-dev`' (and with "`libhdf5-serial-dev`") , as well as without the '`sudo`'.

All of these result in the same error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libhdf5-dev
```

I have made sure `'main, universe, restricted, multiverse'` repositories are all enabled, both from sources.list and from the Ubuntu Software GUI.

Other packages and lib dependencies install just fine with apt, as well as all other apt commands working perfectly. My intention is to install h5py but it always fails upon finding the libhdf5 library doesn't exist.

I have on previous versions of this same ubuntu distribution on this same device installed libhdf5 and then h5py successfully without any issues, but I can't currently figure out why the packages cannot be located.

Is there any reason why this would be happening? How can I install libhdf5? Am I possibly missing something very simple here?

Comment: Have you had any other troubles installing packages on this platform? Maybe a difference mirror would help; the packages you want are there (according to the Ubuntu Packages search page).

Comment: I haven't had any issue installing other packages with `apt-get install` or `apt install`. All of the apt commands seem to work fine, `apt-cache search` returns all my installed dependencies... `apt-get update/upgrade` works fine. I was installing a bunch of libraries together (e.g. `sudo apt-get install <lib1> <lib2> libhdf5-serial-dev') and it correctly installed all other libraries except hdf5 ones, for which it is 'unable to locate package' even though I know it exists.

Comment: So `apt search hdf5` comes up empty, or just the libraries? Really strange - let me know if switching mirrors helps.

Comment: Yep, `apt search hdf5' comes up empty, as well as searching for libhdf5 or any of the hdf5 libraries. Not sure what you mean by 'switching mirrors', bit of an amateur here, any explanation for how to do that would help

Comment: Try running `apt update`, then the search again. If it's still coming up empty, then there must be something wrong with the mirror you're using.

Comment: I ran the update and searched again, and `libhdf5` is still non-existent in response. Could you explain what you mean by something is wrong with the mirror? -- Also, I went onto Ubuntu Software Updates in Settings, changed the 'main server' to 'server from [my country]' and tried again, still no result. I changed it back to 'main server' and received a pop-up saying 'The information about available software is out-of-date' with an option to reload, which opened a pop-up saying 'updating cache' but then said 'Failed to download repository information, check internet connection'.

Comment: *Except my internet connection is working, I am using the device to send these comments here. There is no issue with the internet. Have tried rebooting but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Interesting...I stand corrected. From the download page of **libhdf5-dev** (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libhdf5-dev), it has links to all of the supported architectures. When you click on amd64, the next page shows direct links to download the package. However, clicking arm64 comes up with a page that details the packge, but not an actual download. In this case, you may have to download the source package and build it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y libhdf5-dev
```

Comment: Can you explain why these commands would work when the ones the OP has already tried don’t work?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 16.04 (not 18.04). I solved from [Carol Yuu's suggestion in Nvidia forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/jetson-nano-libhdf5-serial-dev-install-issue/75504/2).

Please try below command and install again:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev
```

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 
HW: Nvidia Jetson TX2